# Linking fortran and c++

Tags: c++, fortran

I have written a very simple example for calling c++ from Fortran but it is not working.
The c++ code is as follows:

```
    #include <iostream>


    void hello_();


    void hello_(){

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;


}
```

And the Fortran code is:

```
  program sayhi
  call hello()
  end program
```

That I compiled the first file with g++ -c hello.cpp and the second with gfortran -c main.f.
But when I try to compile it with g++ main.o hello.o I get the error message:

```
main.o: In function `MAIN__':
main.f:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `hello_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Try ```extern "C" void hello()```